# AppleScript w/ Remote Desktop

Tags: dictionary, applescript, ip-address, remote-desktop

I am relatively new to AppleScript but my main goal is to take a name & IP address and add to Apple Remote Desktop via AppleScript. I have looked over the dictionary for it but being so new I don't understand the dictionaries yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Remote Desktop but we all have "Screen Sharing" in OSX. Using that it's very simple to open a connection to another computer. For example, my computer's sharing name is "mbPro" so this would open that connection in Screen Sharing. Remote Desktop probably has the same command. Good luck.

```
tell application "Screen Sharing"
    GetURL "vnc://mbPro.local"
end tell
```